# Microphone being used in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, audio-recording, microphone, recording

Is there a way to find out whether a microphone/recording device is currently being used by an application in Windows?

I am aware that by using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) one can easily get a list of all recording devices as follows:

```
        public void getAudioDevices()
        {
            DeviceNameByID = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var enumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();

            // Allows you to enumerate rendering devices in certain states
            var endpoints = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(
                DataFlow.Capture,
                DeviceState.Active);
            foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
            {
                float volumeLevel = endpoint.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar;
                Debug.WriteLine($"Volume: {volumeLevel}");
                DeviceNameByID[endpoint.ID] = endpoint.DeviceFriendlyName;
                Debug.WriteLine($"{endpoint.ID}: {endpoint.DeviceFriendlyName} - {endpoint.State}");
            }

            NotificationClient nClient = new NotificationClient();

            // Aswell as hook to the actual event
            enumerator.RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(nClient);
        }
```

but I am not sure as to how/if one can get any knowledge on their current usage.